# Why does the president of the Federation look like a Klingon?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, star-trek, star-trek-vi-undiscovered-country

I always wonder why the president of the *Federation* in [*Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102975/) looks very similar to a *Klingon*. He has the characteristic high hairline, this "Fu Manchu moustache" and, most remarkably, those slight bulges on his forehead (while maybe not as developed as those of actual *Klingons*, they are still noticable). But given that the Federation is in an ongoing conflict with the *Klingons* with the parties only recently approaching each other, this seems quite odd, especially when left without any explanation in the movie. So **is there any explanation for the president's unusual appearance** or am I just imagining things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The President of the Federation according to the Memory Alpha website, is actually an **Efrosian**, and not a Klingon. Granted there are distinct similarities...

Efrosians were invented by Kirk Thatcher, an associate producer on Star Trek IV, in honor of unit production manager Mel Efros.

Comment: I guess my primary mental barrier was that I always considered the *Federation* to be rather earth-centered and thus naturally expected a human to be president.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The Federation was founded in San Francisco, Earth in 2161.  It encompassed 8,000 light years. The total number of formal member worlds was over one hundred and fifty. I guess technically anyone from one of those member worlds could rise to the role of Fed president.